# Two LAN Ports - how to access individually?

Tags: networking

I have a small problem.
Windows 7 32 bit 4GB RAM, built in Ethernet port, PCI card Ethernet port.
Built in port for Internet access.
PCI port for local machine control.

Built in port will have DHCP IP address assigned.
PCI will have fixed IP of 192.168.1.20.

How to specify that Telnet commands go to PCI port and not Internet port?

Mind break!  I meant Netcat not Telnet :((

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "telnet commands"?

Comment: It's a conversion from a LINUX program which did not have Internet access, to Windows.  We now need Internet access as well as machine control port, e.g. was "nc 192.168.1.6 80 < start" since there was originally only one NIC with fixed IP.

Comment: So what is it exactly that's not working the way you want? Or what are you trying to do that's not working? Or what? There shouldn't be anything special you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, David, we seem to be posting concurrently. Actually I'm trying to pre empt potential problems since I do not have the target machine locally to test on and it will need to be done over the Internet.  To explain your question, if I issue the command as above, "nc 192..", how do i know the route will be via 192.168.1.20 and not Internet NIC?

Comment: Are you trying to connect two LAN ports to the same LAN? (And if so, why?)

Comment: Your wording is pretty poor and you should probably check [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Adding a diagram if you don't know how to word a question can help a lot. The decision about which NIC to use is made based on the routing information available to your device.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you two ports (A and B) which are connected to two different networks. By specifying an address that's either within a network connected to A or B and matches a routing entry (`route print`) the decision is made which NIC (network interface card) is being used.

You need to check the routes if it doesn't work. If the DHCP and your fixed network connection are distinct networks you shouldn't have issues.

Comment: Seth, thanks. Bear in mind I'm a Newb as far as Windows networking is concerned. Setting Routes in Windows will take some learning. I looked at (route print) on this computer which does look familiar but controlling it is another matter.

Comment: SOLVED :) I think. This seems to do what I need (route -p add 192.168.1.6 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.20
 OK!)   Hope it helps someone else. Thanks for the prompts.

Comment: It's not so much about being a newbie at windows networking but rather that your question itself isn't easily understood as it is quite vague. Hence the hint to include a diagram. Consider checking out [what to do if someone answers my question](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) as well. ;)

Comment: I'll try and conform in future, Seth. However following "what to do if someone answers my question" gives me two options, Vote or Accept. I possibly cannot Vote since I do not have that privilege and I cannot see any way to Accept unless it means to state that?

Comment: Accepting would be the arrow below the vote buttons on the answer. In addition you should be able to vote from the get go if you normally registered.

Comment: I must be using the wrong browser, Firefox 52, since there no visible arrows on your answer(s) or a "get go" either. You led me to a resolution it would be good to give you the kudos.

Comment: Hmmm. I added a comment 21 hours ago which only shows on page when I click "Add Comment". Strange.